# Calculate CPU Execution time

Tags: performance, cpu

If  I = number of instructions in a program,  CPI = average cycles per instruction

And T = clock cycle time,

(a)  Define CPU Execution Time in terms of I, CPI and T

Consider the data given below:

Clock Rate = 3.1 GHz

Average Cycles per Instruction = 3

Number of instructions in a program =620

(b)  Calculate clock cycle time

(c)  Calculate the CPU execution time`

Comment: yes.please help me to find answers with formulas...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because blatant homework; not about programming.

Answer (score 2):

Just need to understand units:

```
I = instructions
CPI = cycles/instruction
T = clock rate GHz = cycles/time
```

How can you arrange these so you end up with units of time?  You can multiply and divide units just like you do numbers.

Arrange the units in such a way that you end up with time as a result and the relationship will be crystal clear.